# how to trigger overflow-y-auto to work when a children tag exceeds their maximum height

Tags: html, css, tailwind-css

This is my markup

```
<div className="overflow-y-auto h-full w-full">
    <div className="w-full h-[40%]">
        <p>something</p>
    </div>
    <div className="w-full h-[60%]">
        <article>
            some stuff
        </article>
        <article>
            some stuff
        </article>
        <article>
            some stuff
        </article>
    </div>
</div>
```

i want it so when i put more `<article />` , the overflow-y-auto will trigger, with my current setup it is not trigerred since article is inside of its closest div, i can only trigger an overflow on that closest div, any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

If you want the overflow to be triggered for the entire container, including the nested `<div>` elements, you can apply the `overflow-y-auto` class to the outermost `<div>` that wraps all the content.

Here's update code:

```html
<div className="overflow-y-auto h-full w-full">
    <div className="w-full h-[40%]">
        <p>something</p>
    </div>
    <div className="w-full h-[60%] overflow-y-auto">
        <article>
            some stuff
        </article>
        <article>
            some stuff
        </article>
        <article>
            some stuff
        </article>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: That would make the overflow scroll to be on the `<div className="w-full h-[60%] overflow-y-auto">` div,

i still want to scroll past the div with `<p>something</p>`